# User control inside a datagrid cell is resetting

Tags: wpf, datagrid

## User control inside a data grid cell is resetting

My scenario is i have a user control inside a content presenter in a data grid cell. The user control is such that it is curved at the edges. That means i can select the background of cell. When i do so its removing the control and the control is empty after that. i tried to handle it in Begin Edit method but could not. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first of all you should supply some xaml , 
secondly the reason your control is "empty" after clicking the cell is becuase you went into a "Edit" mode when clicking the cell , it just looks like an empty cell , eather set the cell or the entire column as readonly or set the column's CellEditingTemplate 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you eran otzap, it helped me a lot. I made datagrid readonly because i have a control in a cell which is not readonly. so i can use it without editing mode being triggered.